# Theme my Login plugin, how to update fields

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I'm using the [Theme my Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin for a client project and I'm having trouble updating profile fields once a user has been registered;

I followed the instructions [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-adding-new-fields) but they didn't seem to have any effect. If anyone could shed some light on it that would be great.

This is my current code;

`register-form.php`

```
<p>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="phone_number" 
      id="phone_number<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" 
      class="input" 
      value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'phone_number' ); ?>" 
      size="20" 
      tabindex="20" 
      placeholder="Phone Number"
    />
</p>
```

`profile-form.php`

```
<p>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      name="phone_number" 
      id="phone_number" 
      value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->phone_number ); ?>" 
      class="regular-text" 
      placeholder="Phone Number"
    />
</p>
```

`theme-my-login-custom.php`

```
function tml_user_register( $user_id ) {
        // Phone Number
        if ( !empty( $_POST['phone_number'] ) )
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_number', $_POST['phone_number'] );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'tml_user_register' );
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the user meta-information (ie, phone number) is going into the database?

Comment: Yes. Once someone registers, all of their information is there in their profile, but if I want to try and edit that information (To change the phone number for example) it doesn't work

Comment: OK. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook only fires when the user first registers.  To have the custom profile data show up on the Edit User screen, you should use the [`edit_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile) hook (and possibly [`show_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile), if you want users to be able to edit their own custom profile information).